# Exchange 2010 Global "Safe Senders" list, avoid blocking images from corporate domain?

Tags: exchange-2010, content-filter

I've created an email template that is used in our Process Automation software to send out email updates for various reasons.  I've included our corporate logo via an IMG tag with a src pointing to our corporate site. (ex, www.company.net/resources/logo.png).  The problem is, Outlook blocks the image and requires users to click "download images" or even add "company.net" to their safe senders list.

What I would really like to do is be able to define "company.net" as a safe sender at an exchange server level.

Comment: Why not just embed the image?

Comment: We could be talking about thousands of emails a day.  The storage guys would probably be none too happy with me...

Comment: Render your logo in ASCII art and send the messages as plain text!

Comment: @Ward: Something tells me my PR department would not be amused.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996791.aspx

> The BypassedSenderDomains parameter specifies domain name values of
>   sending domains. The Content Filter agent doesn't process any content
>   filtering for messages received from the domains listed on this
>   parameter. To enter multiple domains, separate the addresses by using
>   a comma, for example:contoso.com, example.com. A wildcard character
>   (*) can be used to specify all subdomains, for example:*.contoso.com.
>   The maximum number of domains you can input is 100.

Looks like this might be what I need... I'll see if I can get my exchange guy to try it.  In the mean time, I'll wait for other answers (perhaps something in the management console GUI?)

Comment: Don't expect that. Most of "the good stuff" is only available from the EMS/Powershell. When you manage Exchange Server 2010 from the GUI, the console is actually piecing together powershell scripts that run in the background, so without realizing it, you're already use all the cmdlets :-)

Comment: @Scott, you got the correct command -- set-ContentFilterConfig -bypassedSenderDomain:"domain.com"